# prepareStatement doesn't work with sqlite

Tags: java, sqlite, jdbc, prepared-statement

I try to use prepareStatement to query an sqlite but I encounter an exception:

```
java.sql.SQLException: not supported by PreparedStatment
    at org.sqlite.PrepStmt.unused(PrepStmt.java:328)
    at org.sqlite.PrepStmt.executeUpdate(PrepStmt.java:314)
```

I'm developing my program using Eclipse, so when I click on `at org.sqlite.PrepStmt.unused(PrepStmt.java:328)` it redirects me to `PrepStmt.class` that inside it I found these:

```
@Override
public int executeUpdate(String sql) throws SQLException {
    throw unused();
}
private SQLException unused() {
    return new SQLException("not supported by PreparedStatment");
}
```

This is my code :

```
public static void deleteOp(String word) throws Exception {
    Connection c = null;
    PreparedStatement stmt = null;
    try {
      Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
      c = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionString);
      c.setAutoCommit(false);
      System.out.println("Opened database successfully");

      String sql = "DELETE from " + tableName + " where WORD = ? ;";
      System.out.println(sql);
      stmt = c.prepareStatement(sql);
      stmt.clearParameters();
      stmt.setString(1, word);
      stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
      c.commit();

      stmt.close();
      c.close();
    } catch ( Exception e ) {
        throw e;
    }
    System.out.println("Operation done successfully");
}
```

I want to know is something wrong in my code or Sqlite doesn't support prepareStatement at all or there is a problem with my driver (for example due to being obsolete)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`PreparedStatement` lives a bit of a double life: it `extends Statement`, and thus inherits that class' methods — even though some of them don't really make much sense for `PreparedStatement`.

In this case, `executeUpdate(String)` comes from `Statement` and runs a statement straight-up, without doing the `?` substitutions. It's not what you want: you want just `executeUpdate()`, which is the `PreparedStatement` variant. So in some sense, they're actually doing you a favor by not implementing the `Statement` variant!

Comment: See also [this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/xerial/YMIJga6TDmA) from a few years back. It looks like the sqlite people know about it, but it's not a high-priority issue for them.

Answer (score 7):

You don't need to pass `sql` variable to `executeUpdate` method since you have configured it on `prepareStatement` sentence, so just try:

```
stmt.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: Oh,thanks. I just tried it and it worked. But what a misleading error message it provided!